# Do I correctly understand this definition of Wiener measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am reading the HDR thesis of Joseph Lehec, here:

https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01428644

At page 20 he introduces the Wiener space $(\mathbb W, \mathcal B, \gamma)$, where $\gamma$ is the "Wiener measure", defined as "the law of a standard Brownian motion". Indeed, he introduced a standard n-dim. Brownian motion a few lines before, denoting it by $(B_t)$. For completeness, let me state that $\mathbb W$ is defined as the space of continuous functions $u\colon [0, 1]\to \mathbb R^n$ such that $u(0)=0$, with topology of uniform convergence, and $\mathcal B$ is the associated Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Unfortunately I am not familiar with stochastic processes. My understanding is that this measure $\gamma$ is defined as follows;
$$
\int_{\mathbb W} F(w)\, \gamma(dw)=\int_\Omega F(B(\cdot, \omega))dP(\omega),$$
for all $F\colon \mathbb W\to [0, \infty]$ that is $\mathcal B$-measurable. Here $(\Omega, \mathcal F, dP)$ is the probability space that supports the Brownian motion $(B_t)$.

Is my understanding correct?

**NOTE**. I changed the question after Kavi Rama Murthy made me notice it was meaningless as stated. Thank you. Kavi Rama Murthy's answer refers to the formula
$$\int_{\mathbb W} F(w)\, \gamma(dw)={\sf E}\left[\int_0^1F(B_t)\, dt\right].$$

Comment: Equivalently, for any Borel set $A \subset \mathbb{W}$, we have $\gamma(A) = P(B \in A) = P(\{\omega : B(\cdot, \omega) \in A\})$.  This is just what the word "law" always means.

Comment: Some nice examples of sets $A \subset \mathbb{W}$ to keep in mind: the set of paths which equal 0 at time 1/2; the set of paths that are inside the unit ball at time 1/2; the set of paths which remain inside the unit ball for all times $0 \le t \le 1$; the set of paths which are nowhere differentiable; etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(B_t)$ does not make sense. For  a fixed $\omega$, $B_t(\omega)$ is just a number and not  an element of $\mathbb W$. So you have to evalute $F$ at the entire function $t \to B_t$ and then take the expectation. There is no integral involved here.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot. I edited the question. I think it is OK now.

Comment: It is correct now.